# How to keep rolling log file as per file size?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am working on a project in which I am logging bunch of stuff in a file and I want to make sure my log file is getting rolled as soon as a fixed limit for file is reached. I have a below `logback.xml` file but it looks like file size is not working. I see my file size as 793M but limit I have is 100M

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>process.log</file>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>process%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>9</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %msg%n</pattern>
            <!-- this improves logging throughput -->
            <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
            by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

What wrong I am doing here? And also what is the best policy we should follow in production in terms of logging? We are logging bunch of stuff in a file and we don't want to fill up the disk with this log file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of FileAppender, you should be using a RollingFileAppender.
See: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

You are specifying settings/properties that are intended to be used by the RollingFileAppender and are ignored by FileAppender.

For a good example usage and configuration, refer to this link:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-rollingfileappender-example/

Sample logback.xml using a RollingFileAppender and ConsoleAppender. The RollingFileAppender is both size and time based:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration scan="true">
        <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <Pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>/srv/logs/application.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory> 
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>

            <encoder>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. At the end you have `root level=DEBUG` what does that mean in general? Instead of `DEBUG` if I make it `INFO` then what will happen?

Comment: Setting the root level to debug means that by default you would like all log.debug() calls to be output to file. If you set it to INFO, you will not see DEBUG log statements in your file. It is common in a Production environment to increase the log level to WARN higher to reduce the amount of logging that is output. I commonly use INFO in Production myself and find that is sufficient. You can add specific <Logger> elements in your configuration to 'override' the default:   <logger name="some.package" level="INFO" />

Comment: David, I have tweaked the example again with a simpler variation for you, focused on having a rollover daily for 30 days and a file size maximum of 5Mb.

Comment: Will it roll over daily? Is there any way we can just roll over whenever the file limit is reached to 100MB? I mean just look at file limit and as soon as it reaches 100MB, just rollover to next file and keep maximum 10 file that's all. Is this possible?

Comment: You can change the `<rollingPolicy>` section to a fixed window policy to that the rolling only occurs on size based and a max setting fro the number of files to keep, set by <maxIndex>. For example:    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>application-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

Comment: Will the parent log file be empties after the logs are archieved. I mean, if a have a daily rolling appender, will my parent log have logs from previous days?

Comment: When it rolls the log to start a new one, it will rename the existing application-2.log to application-3.log, application-1.log to application-2.log and application.log to application-1.log. A new and empty application.log will then be created. In the example in my comment above, there is a maxIndex=3. So, before copying application-2.log to application-3.log, the existing application-3.log will be deleted. As long as you have a maxIndex > 0, you will always retain the existing logs as it 'rolls' it to the next log number.

Comment: I used exactly the XML config as above but file is not triggered by size. Any idea what to check?

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel I followed the example in the manual and files were archived when they reached the specified size.  Don't forget the mandatory parameters in the filename, `%d` and `%i`.  See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Comment: @Paul Dont make sense.  How come we are forced to put %d ?  If we put %d, assuming size not yet reach limit,  will the file automatically create new one for each day? If yes, then it does not meet the author requirement, as he is asking for rollover when size limit is reached, not when the current day is over